# pentaho job stops in the middle of a transformation without any indication in log file

Tags: pentaho, transformation

I'm new in using pentaho and I need your help to investigate a problem.
I have scheduled in crontab to run a job by kitchen command. I'm using pentaho release 6.0.1.0.386.
Sometimes (it's not a deterministic problem) one of the transformation stops  after "Loading transformation from repository" and before "Dispatching started for transformation". The log interrupts. No errors. Nothing. And the job doesn't go on.
Any idea? Any check I can do ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

is so many bigger the quantity data in this transformation?

Comment: No. It happens with different transformations (during the building of the dimension tables) but in any case noone of them has a lot of data. In one case they are 1050 rows, in another case 314 rows and last time it stopped during a transformation to build a dimension table with 3 rows.

Answer (score 0):

There are some files that can cause some errors, you can find them in this path:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gt0dd.jpg)
my computer/users / your user / .kettle

If you delete the ones I marked in the image, they will be created automatically when you open the pentaho again.